# Lexical declaration problems with default params

Tags: javascript, referenceerror, default-parameters

I'm having some problems when defining some **functions** after declaring a **class**.

I've used default `params` before when declaring functions, but I don't know if I can use a function or class as default parameter too.

My code is this

```
const Matrix = class {/*...some code...*/}

const sigmoid = function(A, flag = false, factor = 1, Matrix = Matrix) {
    /*my functions declaration*/
}
```

Here I have the problem.

```
var result1 = sigmoid( Matrix.dot( [[val1, val2]], res.W1 ) , false, 1)
var result2 = sigmoid( Matrix.dot(result1, res.W2), false, 1)
```

> In the line of `const sigmoid = ...` it said **can't access lexical declaration `Matrix' before initialization**

Comment: You can, you just must name it differently.

Answer (score 2):

You're *shadowing* your `Matrix` identifier in the declaration by doing this:

```
const sigmoid = function(A, flag = false, factor = 1, Matrix = Matrix) {
// ---------------------------------------------------^
```

That means the `Matrix` after the `=` is the parameter, not the class identifier.

Just use a standard lower-case parameter name instead:

```
const sigmoid = function(A, flag = false, factor = 1, matrix = Matrix) {
// ---------------------------------------------------^
```